# Add URL to lines in specific file

Tags: bash, wget

I am trying to add a URL to individual lines in a list downloaded using `wget`.

The first portion of the Bash script below downloads the list and the URL is static.  The sed command was an attempt to add the URL to the list.

**bash**

```
#!/bin/bash
wget -q --user=xxxx --password=xxxxx --xxxx \
xxx://www.xxx.com/xxxx/xxx/xxxx/list

url=xxx://www.xxx.com/xxxx/xxx/xxxx/

sed s/$url/ list.txt | url_list.txt
sed: -e expression #1, char 14: unknown option to `s'
```

**current list**

```
FilterDuplicates.html
file1.bam
file2.bam
file1.vcf.gz
file2.vcf.gz
```

**desired list** (with the `$url` before the filename)

```
xxx://www.xxx.com/xxxx/xxx/xxxx/FilterDuplicates.html
xxx://www.xxx.com/xxxx/xxx/xxxx/file1.bam
xxx://www.xxx.com/xxxx/xxx/xxxx/file2.bam
xxx://www.xxx.com/xxxx/xxx/xxxx/file1.vcf.gz
xxx://www.xxx.com/xxxx/xxx/xxxx/file2.vcf.gz
```

edit

```
#!/bin/bash
 wget -q --user=xxxx --password=xxxx --xxxx \
 https://www.xxxx.com/xxx/xx/xxxx/file

 $url="https://www.xxxx.com/xxx/xx/xxxx/";
 sed "s|^|$url|" /home/cmccabe/list > /home/cmccabe/url_list.txt
 https://www.xxxx.com/xxx/xx/xxxx/: no such file or directory
```

This is `sed` is close but it appends the url to the end of the file, not to each line like the desired output.  Thank you :)

```
sed -i '$a https://www.xxxx.com/xxx/xx/xxxx/' /home/cmccabe/list
```

**output**

```
FilterDuplicates.html
file1.bam
file2.bam
file1.vcf.gz
file2.vcf.gz
https://www.xxxx.com/xxx/xx/xxxx/
```

**sed command to add text**

```
sed 's/^/https://www.xxxx.com/xxx/xx/xxxx//' /home/cmccabe/list
```

Comment: pluse-uno for sample data, output and code!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pick a separator char (here pipe) not part of your url string.

```
sed 's|^|http://example.com/|' file
```

or if you have the url as a variable, easiest will be using double quotes instead.

```
$ url="http://example.com/"; sed "s|^|$url|" file
```

Comment: I added an edit with the error, but I can access that directory manually.  Thank you :).

Comment: Didn't understand!  You have a directory named "http://..."?  Where is the error coming from?  `sed` doesn't access to the url, only the input/output files specified which seem different.

Comment: I think I just need to use `sed` to add text to the beginning of each line, but get 'sed: -e expression #1, char 13: unknown option to `s''.  I will post my command in the edit.  Thank you :).

Comment: You can't use the delimiter `/` which is in your content as well.  That is the problem.  Use a different delimiter.

Comment: `awk` seems to work without using a different delimiter, but it doesn't do  an in-line update of the file rather it creates a new one. `awk '$0="https://www.xxxx.com"$0' /home/cmccabe/list > url`.  Thank you :).